# How to install the keyboard layout carpalx QGMLWB

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

[Carpalx QGMLWB](http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/carpalx/?full_optimization) is a keyboard layout.

My operating system is Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS 64-bit; my desktop environment is GNOME 3.28.2.

The list of installed keyboard layouts is at Settings > Language and Region > Input Sources, and, at present, it does not contain carpalx QGMLWB.

I want to install carpalx QGMLWB so that it is listed there.

Attempt 1: Sven Hallberg.

I attempted to follow [these instructions](https://www.khjk.org/log/2011/jan/carpalx.html), by Sven Hallberg.
However, my computer does not have the file `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols.dir`.
Herefrom I suspect these instructions are out-of-date.

Attempt 2: X Keyboard Configuration Database.

The webpage that defines carpalx QGMLWB states "Patches to include Carpalx layouts in xkeyboard-config and kbd have been submitted by Perry Thompson."
I have downloaded the most recent version, 2.24, of the X Keyboard Configuration Database [hence](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/XKeyboardConfig).
However, being new to Linux, I cannot work out how to use/install/configure it.

How can I use/install/configure the X Keyboard Configuration Database to install carpalx QGMLWB?

Or is there a better way to install carpalx QGMLWB? If so what is it?

Answer (score 0):

I have Carpalx QGMLWB installed on my Void Linux system. The configuration for X should be distro agnostic. I have:

```
    /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols.dir
    /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/carpalx
```

Note that 'carpalx' is the 'carpalx.xkb' file from Perry Thompson renamed. It is normal for your system to not have the 'symbols.dir' file by default. Test to see if it works by running:

```
$ setxkbmap -layout carpalx
```

Then, make an X configuration file to load the keymap by default:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "keyboard defaults"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "carpalx"
        Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
EndSection
```

Finally, ensure that your desktop environment is not overriding your config file through some other utility.